# How can a generator property be defined in an object literal or class?

Tags: javascript, syntax, properties, generator

JavaScript has syntactic support for property getters in object literals and classes:

```
var stuff = {
    get things() { return ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope']; },
};

class Foo {
    get things() { return ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope']; }
};

// usage
[ ...stuff.things ]

var foo = new Foo;
for (let thing of foo.things) {
   // …
}
```

It also has syntactic support for generator methods:

```
var stuff = {
   *things() { yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope']; },
};

class Foo {
    *things() { return ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope']; }
};

// usage
[ ...stuff.things() ]

var foo = new Foo;
for (let thing of foo.things()) {
   // …
}
```

How can these be combined, defining a generator *property* for an object or class? As non-working examples, combining get syntax and generator method syntax in the obvious ways produces syntax errors:

```
// generates "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'"
var stuff = {
    get* things() {
        yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope'];
    },
};

// generates "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'"
class Foo {
    get *things() {
        yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope'];
    }
};

// generates "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'things'"
stuff = {
    *get things() {
        yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope'];
    },
};

// usage
[ ...stuff.things ];

var foo = new Foo;
for (let thing of foo.things) {
   // …
}
```

NB: though a static array is used in the example, actual use cases would be for generated sequences, such as results from DOM queries; not using a generator isn't a solution. Similarly, while a generator method could be used instead of a property, the same arguments for calculated properties apply (e.g. a method would leak the abstraction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the latest [JavaScript syntax](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-grammar-summary) (from ES2022), getters and generator methods for both object literals and classes come from the [method definition rule](https://262.ecma-international.org/#prod-MethodDefinition). Derivations:

- `ObjectLiteral` → `PropertyDefinitionList` → `PropertyDefinition` → `MethodDefinition`
- `ClassDeclaration`, `ClassExpression` → `ClassTail` → `ClassBody` → `ClassElementList` → `ClassElement` → `MethodDefinition`

From `MethodDefinition`, getters and generator methods match different productions:

```
MethodDefinition:
    GeneratorMethod
    AsyncGeneratorMethod
    "get" ClassElementName "()" "{" FunctionBody "}"
    …
```

There are other rules, but none match a getter or generator.

`GeneratorMethod` further expands to:

```
GeneratorMethod:
    "*" ClassElementName "(" UniqueFormalParameters ")" "{"  GeneratorBody "}"
```

`ClassElementName` is basically an identifier, and so won't match any terminals that mark a getter or generator.

From this, it doesn't appear syntactically possible to define a generator property within an object literal or class. It's possible to add a generator property to an object using `Object.defineProperty`:

```
var stuff = {};
Object.defineProperty(stuff, 'things', {
    get: function*() { yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope']; },
    enumerable: true,
});

class Foo {
}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'things', {
    get: function*() { yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope']; },
    enumerable: true,
});
```

Slightly closer to the intent, a generator method can be defined in the object literal or class, and then turned into a property.

```
var stuff = {
    *things() {
        yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope'];
    },
};
Object.defineProperty(stuff, 'things', {
    get: stuff.things,
    enumerable: true,
});

[ ...stuff.things ];

class Foo {
    *things() {
        yield* ['thimbles', 'care', 'forks', 'hope'];
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'things', {
    get: Foo.prototype.things,
    enumerable: true,
});

var foo = new Foo;
for (let thing of foo.things) {
    // …
}
```

For static class properties, reference the property on the class itself (e.g. `Foo`), rather than the class's prototype (e.g. `Foo.prototype`).